# What does %=% mean in Android.mk for OpenCV4Android?

Tags: android, opencv, makefile

In Android.mk for OpenCVAndroid, there are lines as below:

```
MY_PREFIX := $(LOCAL_PATH)
MY_SOURCES := $(wildcard $(MY_PREFIX)/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(MY_SOURCES:$(MY_PREFIX)%=%)
```

What does %=% mean?
I refer to the manual of GNU make, but fail to find the answer.
What are final local source files ('LOCAL_SRC_FILES')?

Answer (score 1):

**`%` sign means truncate whatever comes on the right of the pattern.**

To me,

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(MY_SOURCES:$(MY_PREFIX)%=%)
```

means

> take `MY_SOURCES` (i.e., *.cpp files under `MY_PREFIX` which is `LOCAL_PATH`) and get whatever comes on the right of `MY_PREFIX`, and then assign it to `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`.

But, I am little confused why they are not stripping out the slash from `MY_SOURCES`. That's, I'd use the following:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(MY_SOURCES:$(MY_PREFIX)/%=%)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Where are the related material about the using of % sign? I still could locate it on the GNU make manual. And why do we need to truncate? We could directly sign the MY_SOURCE to LOCAL_SRC_FILES, I think.

Comment: `MY_SOURCES` includes `MY_PREFIX` path, that's why you need to truncate and can not directly assign to `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`. For reference, see [Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)